# View raw Solr tokens for a single field on a single document

Tags: solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I'm debugging my Solr schema and I'd like to see the results of tokenizing a specific field.

For a simplified example, if I have:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

and I indexed a field with the value `"Hello, worlds!"`, I want to see something along the lines of:

`hello world he el ll lo hel ell llo hell ello hello wo or rl ld wor orl rld worl orld`

to ensure that everything is being tokenized as I envisage it is.

Is this in any way possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Admin > Analysis is exactly what you want.

But there's another great tool that allows you to read index and see how exactly a field or document was indexed.

It's called [Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/) and it's invaluable when troubleshooting and tweaking your schema.

Answer (score 2):

yes, use the Analysis page in the Solr Admin section: [here](http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/analysis.jsp?highlight=on) 
It has exactly that purpose