# Path of Solr Document

Tags: solr, path, indexing, document

I would like to know where the indexed document is saved in solr search.

```
I have installed solr server at C:\solr and using solr 1.4. By making 
necessary changes in the configuration files i am able to search data 
using solr client.
```

Just wondering where that indexed document is saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexed documents are saved in index, which is located in `solr/data/index` folder.

[Here](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/fileformats.html) you can find more details about those files.

From [LuceneFAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#What_are_Segments.3F):

> The index database is composed of 'segments' each stored in a separate
>   file. When you add documents to the index, new segments may be
>   created. These are periodically merged together.

EDIT:
If you want to examine contents of your index and tweak or troubleshoot your schema (analysis), see instructions about the greatest Lucene tool ever, called Luke in [this recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425371/view-raw-solr-tokens-for-a-single-field-on-a-single-document/10427874#10427874).

Comment: Thanks mbonaci !! This is really helpful for me :)