# solr field not found

Tags: mysql, solr

I am new to Solr and have managed to upload about 500K rows from my SQL DB (*pardon my crude attempt at angle-brackets :-):

```
[lst name="statusMessages"]
       [str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">1</str]
       [str name="Total Rows Fetched">499999</str]
       [str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str]
       [str name="Full Dump Started">2012-08-21 22:30:55</str]    
       [str name="">Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 499999 documents. Deleted 0 documents.</str]
       [str name="Committed">2012-08-21 22:31:18</str]
       [str name="Total Documents Processed">499999</str]
       [str name="Time taken">0:0:23.321</str]
 [/lst]
```

The schema for the associated content is:

```
[field name="tid" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" /] 
[field name="ReviewAuthor" type="text_general" indexed="false" stored="true" /]
[field name="ReviewTitle" type="text_general" indexed="false" stored="true" /]         
[field name="ReviewText" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" /] 
[field name="ReviewRating" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true" /] 
[field name="VersionNumber" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" /]
```

However when I attempt to query for `ReviewText` or `ReviewRating`, no results are returned. `tid` on the other had is retrieved but none of the associated other fields are returned. Just `tid + id`.

Any suggestions I could try? thank you in advance.

Ankur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check out what was actually indexed using [Luke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425371/view-raw-solr-tokens-for-a-single-field-on-a-single-document/10427874#10427874).

Then, if you're still unable to solve the problem, report back the findings.

Comment: thank you very much for the tip on Luke. I was unable to query any fields besides ID And TID. so I exported the entire index out to XML and it seems like it only has the ID and TID field related data, none of the other content is in there.  As I have listed above - it does not seem that DataImport reported any errors...is there something else I can look into?

Comment: Can you give me an example of ReviewText and ReviewRating content?

Comment: Are you sure your query is correct? Have you executed it directly in your RDB?

Comment: ReviewText = free text (think of a on Amazon.com or comments on Engadget) ReviewRating - 1 to 5 scale (contains int = 1 through 5) Could you please elaborate what RDB is? I have tried to use the admin tool and Luke - both of them only show ID and TID fields being loaded.

Comment: RDB - your relational database.

Comment: Yes I have and the data is all accounted for. Just takes far too long and hence wanted to move it over to Solr...

Comment: so I just discovered my oversight :-( the database field name had a space in it and was therefore failing on import. an additional issue that might have contributed is that the data query fields did not match up with the schema definition for the field. up and running now though - thank you very much for the suggestions.

Comment: Apologies for losing track of this thread. Thank you again for the help.